Veeam API Full VM Restore non-Virtual Machine folder error
Basically I'm trying to perform full VM restore using latest Veeam REST API.
Used endpoint: /api/v1/restore/vmRestore/vSphere
The issue is that, according to created restoreVM task logs, I'm getting following issue:

Virtual Machine cannot be registered in a non-Virtual Machine folder.

What I've observed so far is that when listing available server inventory objects, I'm getting different folder than available using UI restore wizard directly at Veeam server (via UI I can see correct folder) (for accessing Veeam UI, I'm using separate Admin account)
The endpoint I'm using: /api/v1/inventory/{hostname}
Initially I was blaming diff in access rights for API and Admin account, but both have Veeam Backup Administrator role assigned.
Does anyone experienced something similar? Any ideas?
